# xcodebuild fails even though xcode succeeds on M1 for Simulator

Tags: xcode, apple-m1, xcodebuild

I have a project which is only building in Xcode with Rosetta on my M1. If I open the project in Xcode and build for the simulator it works, but if I build from command line it fails with the error:

```
❌  ld: in /root/Realm/core/librealmcore-ios.a(bptree.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64
```

I will also get this error in Xcode when not using Rosetta. When I run Xcode with Rosetta then the error goes away.

How do I run xcodebuild with Rosetta?

Here's the command I am currently using:

```
xcodebuild build -workspace "MyWorkspace.xcworkspace" -scheme "MyApp" \
    -destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator"
```

Comment: Please include the `architecture error` you are being shown

Comment: Hi I have the same issue, did you find a way of fixing this?